# Modal Popup on Window exit - resets one time

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like to use only one time modal when a user leaves on the Window.

`$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
    if (e.clientY <= 1) {
        //Modal 
    }
});`

Let me know how can I create it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you already have the modal element created in your HTML then I think this should do what you want...

```
$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
  if (e.clientY <= 1 && modalShown != 1) {
    modalShown = 1;
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
  }
});
```